# Partial Captures on Order payment in Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, payment-gateway, spree

I am using Spree and I have modified it as per client requirement. I am stuck at one modification, I need an expert opinion.

---

**Case that Spree provides by default**

Spree provides default payments of auto-capture on/off on order and full payment is captured

---

**Modifications that I want**

with auto-capture mode = off

1. Verify that user has a certain amount in its account that can be less than total amount of order.
2. Make a partial payment capture of that and store remaining amount somewhere.
3. When order gets completed after shipment etc or some other action was done, capture the remaining amount.

---

**My Questions**

1. How should I modify Spree to achieve these tasks?
2. If I make a transaction of $5 with auto-capture = off, Is it possible to capture $10 when transacting that $5 authorization? If it is not possible, then do I have to update this $5 transaction's amount with $10 using OAuth Token. If yes, then how?

---

**Extra Info**

I want gateway independent solution by using Spree Payments classes so that I don't have to configure this for each Gateway I integrate. Right now I have 7-8 gateways including Stripe and Paypal.

---

**Case creation for my problem, just an example**

Total Order Payment = $50.

1. First of all I want to verify that user has $10 in his/her account?
2. If user has $10 then make a transaction with auto capture mode = off and in someway keep remaining amount i.e $50 - $10 in record somewhere.
3. Now I capture $10 and after 2 days shipment gets completed. Now I want to capture that remaining $40 and order gets completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question must be answered in the context of each individual Payment Gateway as each one operates with different rules.

You have asked too many questions to provide a specific answer but generally speaking CNP (Card-Not-Present) transactions do not let you capture above the authorized amount, but it depends on your industry and the deal you have with your merchant and payment processor.

> 2- If I make a transaction of $5 with auto-capture = off, Is it possible to capture $10 when transacting that $5 authorization? If it is not possible, then do I have to update this $5 transaction's amount with $10 using OAuth Token. If yes, then how?

Generally you do not "update" a prior transaction to a different amount (although as I said above, in other industries it is sometimes possible to capture at an amount higher than the authorized amount). You should be authorizing the total amount you *may* want to capture, an then make multiple capture calls to your payment gateway as the goods ship or services are delivered (by CC industry rules, you are generally not allowed to capture until you have delivered the service.)

I don't know of any Payment gateways that use "Oauth tokens" for communication, that is generally an authentication-based, not API based, technology.

> -> I want gateway independent solution by using Spree Payments classes so that I don't have to configure this for each Gateway I integrate. Right now I have 7-8 gateways including Stripe and Paypal.

Sounds like a huge disaster. Get rid of them, the time debugging each gateway alone makes this an absolutely insane idea.

> Total Order Payment = $50.
>   1) First of all I want to verify that user has $10 in his/her account?

Generally you can't "peak" into someone's private bank account and see how much money they have-- this is a feature you invented. What you can do is authorize the total amount you might want to charge in the future.

> 2) If user has $10 then make a transaction with auto capture mode = off and in someway keep remaining amount i.e $50 - $10 in record somewhere.
>   3) Now I capture $10 and after 2 days shipment gets completed. Now I want to capture that remaining $40 and order gets completed.

What you need is one authorization with multiple captures. Call your Payment processor representative and have a conversation about this with them and see what rules govern your merchant and processor accounts.

Comment: Yea. From Last few days I had been on exploring mission and had got all my answers. You are correct in almost everything. I will make a thorough answer including your answers  for this post and will post them. And thanks a lot for your time.